# TensorFlow error: logits and labels must be same size

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to learn TensorFlow by implementing ApproximatelyAlexNet based on various examples on the internet. Basically extending the AlexNet example [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/alexnet.py) to take 224x224 RGB images (rather than 28x28 grayscale images), and adding a couple more layers, changing kernel sizes, strides, etc, per other AlexNet implementations I've found online.

Have worked through a number of mismatched shape type errors, but this one has me stumped:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=dim { size: 49 } dim { size: 10 } labels_size=dim { size: 1 } dim { size: 10 }
     [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Softmax, _recv_Placeholder_1_0/_13)]]
     [[Node: gradients/Mean_grad/range_1/_17 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_457_gradients/Mean_grad/range_1", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

The 49 dimension is particularly puzzling. For debugging, my batch size is currently 1, if I increase it to 2 then the 49 becomes 98.

If I log the shape of the x and y that I pass to

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batchImages, y: batchLabels, keepProb: P_DROPOUT})
```

I get

```
x shape: (1, 150528)
y shape: (1, 10)
```

Which is as expected: 150528 = 224 * 224 RGB pixels, and a one-hot vector representing my labels.

Would appreciate any help in figuring this out!

**Update:** code exhibiting the fault here:

https://gist.github.com/j4m3z0r/e70096d0f7bd4bd24c42

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code as a Gist. There are two changes that are necessary to make the shapes agree:

1. The line:

   ```
   fc1 = tf.reshape(pool5, [-1, wd1Shape[0]])
   ```

   ...is responsible for the erroneous `49` in the batch dimension. The input is 1 x 7 x 7 x 256, and it is reshaped to be 49 x 256, because `wd1Shape[0]` is 256. One possible replacement is the following:

   ```
   pool5Shape = pool5.get_shape().as_list()
   fc1 = tf.reshape(pool5, [-1, pool5Shape[1] * pool5Shape[2] * pool5Shape[3]])
   ```

   ...which will give  `fc1` the shape 1 x 12544.
2. After making this change, the size of the `'wd1'` weight matrix (256 x 4096) doesn't match the number of nodes in `fc1`. You could change the definition of this matrix as follows:

   ```
       'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([12544, 4096])),
   ```

   ...although you may want to modify the other weights, or perform additional pooling to reduce the size of this matrix.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I think I can work with that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Follow-up question: is there a way to get TensorFlow to fail in a more informative manner in this instance? It seems like TF could have figured out that there were mismatched shapes at exactly the line you flagged.

Comment: I think the problem is the -1 in the reshape, which acts as a wildcard and (in this case) loses information about the leading dimension. This makes it hard for TensorFlow to know the true shape without running the program, and there might even be valid programs where you split a single example into 49 smaller examples. We probably need better ways of expressing batch-size invariant transformations to avoid this (`tf.expand_dims()` and `tf.squeeze()` are helpful but maybe we need a `tf.flatten_dims()` for this case).

Comment: @mrry, Thanks for the answer above. I am somehow not not able to understand the solution. I have a batch size if 15 and I get the error that it should be equal to label size of (315,3). 315 is my training set and 3 is my number of classes. I don't understand how to make my batch size equal to that?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when using model.fit(..). 
Turns out my output_size was defined as 2 while using "binary_crossentropy" as the loss function, when it should have been defined as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you didn't provide an actual code you are using it's hard to exactly say what's wrong.

Here are some general tips for debugging such problems:

- Add `print(tensor.get_shape())` to the places related to the problem (in your case dense2, out, _weights['out'], _biases['out'] are suspects).
- Make sure your matrix multiplications are in right order (e.g. dense2 by _weights['out'], should result in batch_size x 10 matrix).

If you modified the code in AlexNet you linked, you probably have changed next lines:

```
 dense1 = tf.reshape(norm3, [-1, _weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]]) # Reshape conv3 output to fit dense layer input
 dense1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(dense1, _weights['wd1']) + _biases['bd1'], name='fc1') # Relu activation
 dense2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(dense1, _weights['wd2']) + _biases['bd2'], name='fc2') # Relu activation
 out = tf.matmul(dense2, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
```

Probably shape of `dense2` is [49, 1024] in your case. You can check by adding a print `dense2.get_shape()`. You should prints for shapes for all the tensors until you find one that gets 49. I can only guess what you changed, but it can be one of reshapes.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've uploaded a gist here which is standalone and demonstrates the issue:

https://gist.github.com/j4m3z0r/e70096d0f7bd4bd24c42

You're right: the max pooling layer ends up with size 7x7 = 49.

Comment: Ok, making some headway: adding more maxpool layers after the various convolutions reduces the 49 to a 4, which I think makes sense: we're starting from higher resolution input, so we need more maxPool layers to result in commensurate downsampling of the input.

Comment: The first dimension should be batch size, so even if it's 4 - it still incorrect. I think the problem `fc1 = tf.reshape(pool5, [-1, wd1Shape[0]])` is in this line. When you do -1 - it pretty much captures the rest of the pool5 side. Try replacing -1 with 1 (your batch size) and see if there is a mismatch - and correct the reshaping from `wd1Shape[0]` to what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because your class variable and label is not matching.

ex:- 
In your code, You declared class variable as 10
But label might not be 10.

Once you made your class variable and label same dimension. This issue will be resolved.